# svnversion, build numbers and "exported"

Tags: xcode, svn

When I run `svnversion` from the command line, I see version "3978" which is correct.

However, when I run this in a build script in Xcode 4.6.3 from the same directory I see "exported".

Why is this and how can I resolve this?

(My client and server are on SVN 1.7. According to the [redbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html), this can happen when `svnversion` is invoked on a directory that is not a working copy but this perhaps doesn't seem to be the case here.)

Answer (score 0):

Digging into Xcode 4.6.3's package contents, in `Contents/Developer/usr/bin` the version of svn bundled with Xcode is 1.6.18, while the system version is 1.7.10. This seems to explain the mismatch.

Symlinking to `/opt/local/bin/svn*` in `Contents/Developer/usr/bin` resolved this for me.